# Previous and next buttons are not next to each other

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I am using jquery datatables in a project. These are the scripts I have included at the end of my page:

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-
1.10.13/datatables.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
<script 
src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" 
/>
```

The problem is that the `previous`,`page` and `next` buttons are not next to each other. [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should include the css between `<head></head>` tags, not at the end of the page, maybe that's the problem? If that's not the issue, then please post your html/css code for those buttons.